# How to validate Kendo Date in .Net MVC should not exceeding today's date ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to validate Kendo Date in .Net MVC should not exceeding today's date ? 
And also having the date format as MMDDYYYY with no timings on it.

Date of Birth should not exceed today's date and just need only the date.

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.BirthDate))
                            <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we use. Take out the Min if you allow dead people :)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.BirthDate)
              .Enable(false)  // or some condition
              .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
              .Min(new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
              .Max(DateTime.Today)
)
```

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/rangeselection

Also, my model has:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve.. and how do you disable the calendar ?   If i have to show only as Read Only . Not allowing the user to select the date

Comment: See edit. You can use .Enable(false) or if you prefer jquery.

Comment: in details - on showing the date in a label.. i am seeing  the Time along with it.  @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.BirthDate)    . Is there a way to trim the timing. Date shows as 8/9/2008 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Add an annotation to your model (see edit) for date format or use `@Model.BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`